# fadein fadeout ignores time delay

Tags: jquery

Can someone figure out why the fadein and fadeout are not working? What is happening is that the appended div shows up and is removed almost immediately. I have a delay of 2500 which should keep the div present long enough to read it.

I'm really new to JQuery so if there is a better way to construct this, I'd love to hear a better or cleaner way of doing it.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "2.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
      var div = $('<div>').attr('id', 'message').html(data.message).css('position', 'absolute').css('top', '300px').css('left', '1000px');
      if(data.success == 0)
      {
        $(div).addClass('ajax-error');
      }
      else
      {
        $(div).addClass('ajax-success');
      }

      $('body').append(div);
      $("#message").fadeIn(2500, function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(300, function() {
          $(this).remove();
        });
      });
    }
  });
```

This is a block of code I am using to do validation and works as I expect it to by fading in long enough to read the error then fading out. All I've done is simply copy the fadein and out block of code into my ajax block.

```
    var div = $('<div>').attr('id', 'error').html('Cannot Be Blank').hide();
    $(div).addClass('ajax-error').css('position', 'absolute').css('top', '300px').css('left', '1000px');
    $('body').append(div);
    $("#error").fadeIn(2500, function() {
      $(this).fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    });
    return false;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("<div>")
    .attr( "id", "message" )
    .html( data.message )
    .css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "300px",
        "left": "1000px",
        "display": "none"
    })
    .addClass( data.success ? "ajax-success" : "ajax-error" )
    .appendTo( "body" )
    .fadeIn()
    .delay( 2500 )
    .fadeOut();
```

I added display:none to the CSS declarations. You should hide it at first, so that it can fade in correctly.

However, if it doesn't work for you, it could be that it's because you're using an older version of jQuery. The delay() method was introduced in 1.4.

Comment: Thanks Šime but there is no fadein or out. The div appears correctly but there are no effects and the div is not removed.

Comment: I like your method a bit better as it's cleaner than my code. Any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: @Jim I added display:none. Also, the code will not work if you don't have jQuery version 1.4, unfortunately.

Comment: OK Sime but I believe I am using 1.4. Actually, I'm using the JQuery from Google so I'd imagine that it's 1.4, no? I'll give your code a shot now. brb

Comment: Well Sime, you are correct. It does work with 1.4 and I was on 1.3x. Thank you.

Comment: @Jim definitely upgrade to 1.4 if possible, it has some significant speed improvements (plus new features, as illustrated!).

Comment: @Jim Cool :) However, consider using a smaller value for the "left" property. 1000px is pretty large - visitors with narrow browser windows might not see the message at all.

Comment: Sime, honestly, I hate having to use absolute positioning and what I wanted to do was to control exactly where the error / success message would be placed. I posted that question last night but nobody could seem to figure it out. Might you know how to do this so I can totally get rid of the absolute positioning? This is what I really want to do. :)

Comment: @Jim Absolute positioning is OK. For example you can display the message as a bar at the top of the web-page: `positon: absolute; left: 0; right:0; top: 0; height: 100px; background-color:yellow;`. That should look OK.

Comment: OK, I can do that too. If I wanted to display the message on the right portion of the screen near where I have my form, what is the preferred method for this? The website is designed for 1220px width and the form is located on the right portion of it.

Comment: @Jim Try this: `#formContainer { position:relative; }` and then you append the message to the form-container instead of BODY: `.appendTo("#formContainer")`. Now the absolute position is relative to the form-container element. For example if you define this CSS for the message: `position:absolute; right:0; top:0; width:400px;` then the message will be placed in the top-right corner of the form container.

Comment: Hey, that seems to work... :) What is the difference between absolute positioning as we originally had it, appending to the body and this method? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I created a div with an id of formContainer because JQuery will no longer append the message to the body. Was this right?

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding because I created a table with 2 cells next to each other. I was expecting to see the error message in the cell where I placed the formContainer div.

Comment: @Jim Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relatively to the closest relatively positioned ancestor element. So, if you have a position:abslute #message and you place it in a position:relative #formContainer, then the left/right/top/bottom CSS properties of the #message will determine the position of the #message in the #formContainer. I recommend you to read a tutorial on absolute/relative positioning to fully understand that concept.

Answer (score 3):

The 2500 is not a delay, it's the length of time the fadeIn takes to complete. What is happening is that as soon as it fades in, the 'complete' callback function is executed, making it fade out in 300 ms.

If you want it to stay for 2.5 secs than disappear, you could use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.setTimeout) in the callback function. Something like

```
   $("#message").fadeIn(400, function() {
     setTimeout(function(){
        $("#message").fadeOut(300, function() {$("#message").remove();})
        },2500);
   });
```

I'll post my test page just for the heck of it, to illustrate this method.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#message").fadeIn(400, function() {
          setTimeout(function(){
              $("#message").fadeOut(300, function() {
              $("#message").remove();})},2500);
              });
            });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='message'>
      Message!!
      <br>
      <img src='http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/2456.jpg'>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Using `$.delay`, the fading part could be

```
$("#message").fadeIn(400, function() {
  $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut(300,function(){$(this).remove()});});
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. How do I fix it?

Comment: What doesn't make sense to me is that I have another construct above the ajax bloc where I am doing validation and have the exact same fadein and fadeout block and functions exactly as I want. I don't understand what is different from my validation block to the ajax block

Comment: Thanks again for helping me with this Alex. I've tried your code but the div appears and stays there. There is no fadein or out at all. It's just stuck on.

Comment: My code was screwed up. I just fixed it and tested it (there was a comma in the wrong place - sorry).

Comment: @Alex Why not just: `fadeIn().delay(2500).fadeOut()` ?

Comment: @Šime Vidas I just don't think about jQuery methods that much. Good suggestion. It's good to know both ways.

Comment: @Alex. I was going to ask the same thing. :) So, me being a total noob to JQuery... Which one of these suggestions is the better way to go?

Comment: Either one. I'm adding a tested version using .delay(), too. It might be seen as more elegant to use jQuery methods when available.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'll try this now. Honestly though, I'm still clueless as to why my validation block fades in and out as I think it should but the exact same code in the ajax block does not. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @Jim I'm not sure. It is the same code of course, and logically, should have the same unintended behavior.

Comment: I agree. It is really strange. It's ashame that I don't know more JavaScript, really. Your code does work too. Thanks. I just upgraded my JQuery from 1.3 to 1.4.4.

Comment: @Alex However, notice the redundancy in your code. You are selecting the same #message element three times. It would aid your performance and reduce error-proneness if you put the jQuery object into a variable, and then work with the variable: `var $message = $("#message"); $message.fadeIn(....`

Comment: @Šime Agreed - it was just a quick example. That is, of course what I do in my own projects, too. (I changed it because `$(this)` wasn't working in the context of the setTimeout function).